# How can I extract the substring of a document string using RegEx?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have gotten the body text of a medical document using BeautifulSoup from a :

```
import requests  
r = requests.get('https://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp? 
Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2332-Abdominal%20Abscess%20I&D')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'sampletext'})

body_text = soup.find('body').text
```

The web page the text was scraped from was not designed with any semantic markup, it's just a big blob of text with bold headings. The body text is as follows:

```
'\n\n\n\n\n \nTranscribed Medical Transcription Sample Reports and Examples\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\r\n(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});\r\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n|\n\n\n\n\n\nvar addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true};\nView this sample in Blog format on MedicalTranscriptionSamples.com\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\r\n(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});\r\n\n\n\n\n\nvar addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true};\n\n\n Sample Type / Medical Specialty:  Gastroenterology\nSample Name: Abdominal Abscess I&D \n Description:  Incision and drainage (I&D) of abdominal abscess, excisional debridement of nonviable and viable skin, subcutaneous tissue and muscle, then removal of foreign body.\r\n        (Medical Transcription Sample Report)\n\nPREOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS:  Abdominal wall abscess.POSTOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS:  Abdominal wall abscess.PROCEDURE:  Incision and drainage (I&D) of abdominal abscess, excisional debridement of nonviable and viable skin, subcutaneous tissue and muscle, then removal of foreign body.ANESTHESIA:  LMA.INDICATIONS:  Patient is a pleasant 60-year-old gentleman, who initially had a sigmoid colectomy for diverticular abscess, subsequently had a dehiscence with evisceration.  Came in approximately 36 hours ago with pain across his lower abdomen.  CT scan demonstrated presence of an abscess beneath the incision.  I recommended to the patient he undergo the above-named procedure.  Procedure, purpose, risks, expected benefits, potential complications, alternatives forms of therapy were discussed with him, and he was agreeable to surgery.FINDINGS:  The patient was found to have an abscess that went down to the level of the fascia.  The anterior layer of the fascia was fibrinous and some portions necrotic.  This was excisionally debrided using the Bovie cautery, and there were multiple pieces of suture within the wound and these were removed as well.TECHNIQUE:  Patient was identified, then taken into the operating room, where after induction of appropriate anesthesia, his abdomen was prepped with Betadine solution and draped in a sterile fashion.  The wound opening where it was draining was explored using a curette.  The extent of the wound marked with a marking pen and using the Bovie cautery, the abscess was opened and drained.  I then noted that there was a significant amount of undermining.  These margins were marked with a marking pen, excised with Bovie cautery; the curette was used to remove the necrotic fascia.  The wound was irrigated; cultures sent prior to irrigation and after achievement of excellent hemostasis, the wound was packed with antibiotic-soaked gauze.  A dressing was applied.  The finished wound size was 9.0 x 5.3 x 5.2 cm in size.  Patient tolerated the procedure well.  Dressing was applied, and he was taken to recovery room in stable condition.\r\n        \n\n\n\n\n\r\n     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});\r\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\r\n(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});\r\n\n\n\nKeywords: \r\n        gastroenterology, excisional debridement, subcutaneous tissue, abdominal wall abscess, foreign body, abdominal abscess, bovie cautery, abdominal, i&d, wound, incision, abscess, \r\n         \r\n                      \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n  \n\n\nNOTE: These\r\n            transcribed medical transcription sample reports and examples are provided by various users and\r\n            are for reference purpose only. MTHelpLine does not certify accuracy and quality of sample reports.\r\n            These transcribed medical transcription sample reports may include some uncommon or unusual formats;\r\n            this would be due to the preference of the dictating physician. All names and dates have been\r\n            changed (or removed) to keep confidentiality. Any resemblance of any type of name or date or\r\n            place or anything else to real world is purely incidental.\n\n\n\n\n\nHome | MedicalTranscriptionSamples | MT911 | MTDictionary | MTSetup | MTHelpLine\nSitemap | Tell\r\n              a Friend | Contact\r\n              Us | Disclaimer\n\n\n\n\nTranscribed Medical Transcription Sample Reports and Examples\n\n\n\n\n\r\n  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){\r\n  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),\r\n  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)\r\n  })(window,document,\'script\',\'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js\',\'ga\');\r\n\r\n  ga(\'create\', \'UA-1275448-3\', \'auto\');\r\n  ga(\'send\', \'pageview\');\r\n\r\n\n'
```

I want to extract the substring of the document text starting with the `Sample Type / Medical Specialty` field and ending with the `TECHNIQUE` field. In order to extract this substring of text I am attempting to use regex to parse out the characters directly before the `Sample Type / Medical Specialty` field and directly after the `TECHNIQUE` field:

```
import re

try:
    found = re.search('addthis_config = 
{"data_track_clickback":true};\n\n\n(.+?)\r\n        \n\n\n\n\n\r\n     
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []', body_text).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    # Start/Stop markers not found in the original string
    found = ''
```

Clearly this is wrong but hopefully I get my point across that I'm trying to find a common start and stop markers of the body text. If you have any feedback or pointers on how to implement this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: you can use [`Sample Type \/ Medical Specialty.*?TECHNIQUE`](https://regex101.com/r/uUJPSs/1/)

Comment: @CodeManiac Thank you for this!  The hyperlink is very helpful - I am trying to grab all of the contents in the TECHNIQUE field, however, with the last sentence being 'Dressing was applied, and he was taken to recovery room in stable condition.'  Since this is followed by an /r/n I am not sure how to implement this into the regex?

Comment: `\s` you can simply use `\s+` to match space characters

Comment: @CodeManiac I'd also like to have the regex apply to other sample documents on the same web page I was scraping from so I would prefer not to simply just define the ending of the last sentence I would like to subset but rather something that will be tagged following that last sentence.

Comment: it's fine you can have generic one but there must be some sort of pattern to for stopping the match, in the one i suggested was `TECHNIQUE` similarly if there's any generic pattern you see in your text, we can simply make it generic

Comment: I suppose `Sample Type \/ Medical Specialty.*?adsbygoogle` gets me close enough to where I need to be

Comment: I can't seem to implement this outside of the regex101.com environment.  When I am running the following in my python environment it seems that the regex is not being found within the document string:  `import re

try:
    found = re.search('Sample Type \/ Medical Specialty.*?adsbygoogle', body_text).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    found = '' `

Comment: there's no capturing group in our regex as far as i know `.group()` is used to access captured group ( pardon if i am wrong as i don't have much context of python )

Comment: No worries.  I guess my point is even when I attempt to run `re.search('Sample Type \/ Medical Specialty.*?adsbygoogle', body_text)` the substring is not found within the document and nothing is returned.

Comment: it does you can see [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/uUJPSs/3/)

Comment: Although it is showing the highlighted portion I am interested in when trying the same regex expression 'Sample Type \/ Medical Specialty.*?adsbygoogle` on regex101.com - just can't seem to replicate this in python

Comment: try running this [`code`](https://regex101.com/r/uUJPSs/3/codegen?language=python) and see

Comment: here's [`python demo`](https://onlinegdb.com/SyRtJBubS)

Comment: You are the best!  Thank you that finally worked for me

Comment: i have added this as [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57024888/9624435) you can check

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this expression:

```
Sample Type \/ Medical Specialty\s*:\s*(.*?)TECHNIQUE
```

might simply return that.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Spg7lw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
Sample Type \/ Medical Specialty.*?adsbygoogle
```

[image]

[`python demo`](https://onlinegdb.com/SyRtJBubS)|[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/uUJPSs/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This page is *semi-structured*, each block begins with `<b>` tag which contains title followed by `":"` sign. We grab this title and next sibling with `next_sibling()` call and you get your data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2332-Abdominal%20Abscess%20I&D'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

data = [(title.get_text(strip=True).replace(':', ''), title.next_sibling.strip()) for title in soup.select('#sampletext b:contains(":")')]

from textwrap import wrap

for (title, text) in data[:-1]: # -1 because we don't want last 'Keywords' row
    print('Title:', title)
    print('Text:')
    print('\n'.join('\t' + t for t in wrap(text, width=70)))
    print('*' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Title: Sample Type / Medical Specialty
Text:
    Gastroenterology
********************************************************************************
Title: Sample Name
Text:
    Abdominal Abscess I&D
********************************************************************************
Title: Description
Text:
    Incision and drainage (I&D) of abdominal abscess, excisional
    debridement of nonviable and viable skin, subcutaneous tissue and
    muscle, then removal of foreign body.
********************************************************************************
Title: PREOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS
Text:
    Abdominal wall abscess.
********************************************************************************
Title: POSTOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS
Text:
    Abdominal wall abscess.
********************************************************************************
Title: PROCEDURE
Text:
    Incision and drainage (I&D) of abdominal abscess, excisional
    debridement of nonviable and viable skin, subcutaneous tissue and
    muscle, then removal of foreign body.
********************************************************************************
Title: ANESTHESIA
Text:
    LMA.
********************************************************************************
Title: INDICATIONS
Text:
    Patient is a pleasant 60-year-old gentleman, who initially had a
    sigmoid colectomy for diverticular abscess, subsequently had a
    dehiscence with evisceration.  Came in approximately 36 hours ago with
    pain across his lower abdomen.  CT scan demonstrated presence of an
    abscess beneath the incision.  I recommended to the patient he undergo
    the above-named procedure.  Procedure, purpose, risks, expected
    benefits, potential complications, alternatives forms of therapy were
    discussed with him, and he was agreeable to surgery.
********************************************************************************
Title: FINDINGS
Text:
    The patient was found to have an abscess that went down to the level
    of the fascia.  The anterior layer of the fascia was fibrinous and
    some portions necrotic.  This was excisionally debrided using the
    Bovie cautery, and there were multiple pieces of suture within the
    wound and these were removed as well.
********************************************************************************
Title: TECHNIQUE
Text:
    Patient was identified, then taken into the operating room, where
    after induction of appropriate anesthesia, his abdomen was prepped
    with Betadine solution and draped in a sterile fashion.  The wound
    opening where it was draining was explored using a curette.  The
    extent of the wound marked with a marking pen and using the Bovie
    cautery, the abscess was opened and drained.  I then noted that there
    was a significant amount of undermining.  These margins were marked
    with a marking pen, excised with Bovie cautery; the curette was used
    to remove the necrotic fascia.  The wound was irrigated; cultures sent
    prior to irrigation and after achievement of excellent hemostasis, the
    wound was packed with antibiotic-soaked gauze.  A dressing was
    applied.  The finished wound size was 9.0 x 5.3 x 5.2 cm in size.
    Patient tolerated the procedure well.  Dressing was applied, and he
    was taken to recovery room in stable condition.
********************************************************************************
```

EDIT: For grabbing the `<b>` tags which contains `:` character I use CSS selector `#sampletext b:contains(":")`.

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**